# Creating Coupon counter click

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a coupon click counter.

I received the default number of clicks using the code

```
<?php $couponusers = get_field('coupon_users'); ?>
```

And I displayed the default number of clicks using the code,

```
<p><?php echo $couponusers ?></p>
```

Now, I want to increase the value of ‘coupon_users’ whenever a click is made. Any suggestions on how to do this?

The page I need help with: https://deals.onlinerockershub.com/bluehost-web-hosting/

Comment: use `update_field`?

Comment: I assume you're using ACF Plugin. You can create filter in your `functions.php` file with `update_field()` that will trigger on each page hit, and possibly you're going to use Cookies (&, or) Sessions to make sure that someone is not going to hit twice.

Comment: @HarisDevel Yes, I understand that I should use update_field. Could, you provide me the code, that I should add in `functions.php`?

Comment: I found from ACF documentation that I should use, `update_field('coupon_users',$couponusers)` But, I don't know how to increment `$couponusers`, when a click is made?

Answer (score 0):

Add this action to your functions.php

`function coupon_callback() {
    //
    // Add here cookie check
    //
    if(is_page('1')){ // ID of "Thank you for coupon click" page
        update_field('coupon_users',$couponusers); // or similar
    }
    return;
}
add_filter( 'wp', 'coupon_callback' );`

Comment: Thanks for the code @HarisDevel I placed the following code,      
`function coupon_callback() {
    //
    // Add here cookie check
    //
    if(is_page('6396')){ // ID of "Thank you for coupon click" page
     $couponusers = get_field('coupon_users',45);
     $couponusers = $couponusers+1;
        update_field('coupon_users',$couponusers,45); // or similar
    }
    return;
}
add_filter( 'wp', 'coupon_callback' );`     This helped me to change the coupon counter on click for a single page. Now, I want to use this for all posts, with different destination pages.

Comment: I assume you're going to put "Add coupon" button everywhere. In that case you will need to put button inside of form that have action to current page. Then, in your function replace `if(is_page)` with `$_POST` handler (`if($_POST coupon_button)`).